# NTP solution for network of Raspberry Pi devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, ntp

I've built my own digital signage solution based around the Raspberry Pi. Basically all of the Pi's are scattered around one city in the midwest (for now), and they ask for hourly updates from a VPS that happens to be physically located in Dallas. The actual displaying by the Pi is done via a webapp in chromium that opens on boot, and uses javascript to cycle through content at defined intervals.

As an example, say two of these displays are in the same location, each changing the image on the screen every 4 seconds. And assume for the hour starting at 15:00, they are given the same list of content to cycle through by the server. When 15:00 rolls around, both display content item A, wait 4 seconds, display content item B, etc. before coming back around to A again.

As the raspberry pi has no real time clock chip, both would be getting all of their time information via NTP. ntp.conf tells me:

"pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will pick a different set every time it starts up."

And this works well almost all of the time, as these two screens would appear to be perfectly synchronized,changing to the same thing at the same time, but every now and then I catch them de-synced for a little while.

My theory is that since they are selecting different NTP servers from the pool (and maybe some of these are far away etc.), they are getting different enough time updates for one to think it is 15:00:005 and the other to think it is 15:00:00.

Finally arriving at the question (sorry), would it be worth it for me to set up my Dallas server as the only NTP server for all my scattered Pi's? Even if the Dallas server is wrong by a few seconds, at least they would all be synchronized, ignoring the fact that one Pi's data may take a different route to Dallas than another's, therefore making the time update slightly incorrect. To clarify, I don't care if the Pi thinks it's 15:00:005 when it's actually 15:00:00, I just want them ALL to think it's 15:00:005.

Maybe I'm worrying about it too much, or underestimating the accuracy of 3-4 low-stratum NTP servers even if they are far away. Thought it would at least be an interesting question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *would it be worth it for* - how much $$$ does it cost you because the Pi's are a twentieth of a second out from each other? $0? No it's not *worth* it. But you should at least change them to use [us.pool.ntp.org](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/us) to stay with USA only internet traffic.

Comment: It doesn't cost me any money, I meant worth it as in a gain of synchronization precision across the devices. It just irks me when I see them slightly off.  Granted, it's not often, but I guess I'm easily irked. And yes I should be doing that, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I don't get your problem. Just use the same pool?!

Comment: I took "pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will pick a different set every time it starts up." in ntp.conf to mean each pi is getting information from four different servers in different places, creating the time discrepancy that made my displays de-synced.

Comment: If this is not the case, and it's a rotating set of four, so all pi's are getting time from the same four at all times, then just changing it to the US pool would probably be fine. I'm trying to figure out which of those two methods it uses.

Comment: All of the pis are not getting the same 4 pool servers all of the time. Depending on the DNS cache they might have different servers. Regardless all pool servers are very close to utc and the ntpd on the Pis will groom the time. I find it very hard to beleive that any visually noticeable sync issues are the result of ntpd's algos for time sync.

Comment: I didn't really believe it either, thought it might be something wrong with my code.  But while two of them weren't synced I logged into both and found that one thought the time was about two seconds ahead of the other. For now I've set them all to prefer the four closest stratum 1 servers to my city, and use the US pool as a backup. I'm assuming this will be good enough. Thank you all for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your error window (it seems very narrow)

1. You point them all to the same exact NTP server (maybe your own) and get an error about your packet round-trip along the day, this might get you even seconds of precision depending on your network.
2. Install a GPS module, GPS satellites broadcast a **very** precise hour. They even have position info so you can tell how skewed your timestamp is. This is very precise if done correctly, there are even wireless network broadcast systems using this technique for data synchronization.

Comment: I basically did #1 on your list, and I probably won't do much else to be honest as I want to control costs for each device. I have the same four stratum 1 servers, all reasonably close, for each Pi now, with the four US pool servers after those. They are all within milliseconds, and things only look de-synced when you get into the hundreds of milliseconds. Thanks for the reply, you're the only answer and I already pretty much implemented what you suggested, so I'll give it to you.

Comment: You can increase your chances of good sync by making them all ask for the ntptime at the same time, probably at 3am or so. This is of course all non deterministic as it depends on network conditions. But I bet your sync will be in the range of a second.